# Estimation system of simultaneous equations

Tags: r, stata, systemfit

I am trying to estimate the following system of simultaneous equations with 3 endogenous variables using **R**:

```
y~a+B
B~c+D
D~f+g
```

Actually I am trying to repeat results from **Stata**. The code in Stata using *3SLS* method is

```
reg3 (y=a B) (B=c D) (D=f g)
```

In R I am using *systemfit* package.

```
library("systemfit")
systemfit(data, list(y~a+B, B~c+D,D~f+g), method = "3SLS")
```

But this function is requested instrument variables for 3SLS estimation.

What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `inst` argument. More can be found in the vignette of the `systemfit` package. It has some very good examples. You can have a look at Klein model replication in the vignette.